# How can I save all Scrapy HTML files to S3?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, scrapy

I would like to set up a system to save all HTML files Scrapy finds to s3. Then before pulling any page, I would like to check if that page has already been scraped and stores to S3.

I have looked at scrapy's ITEM_PIPELINES, but that seems like it's only for the parse_item function?

If I have multiple spiders, it seems silly to have to add a line like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.push_and_save_to_s3(response.text)

def parse_item(self, response):
    self.push_and_save_to_s3(response.text)
```

Is there some middleware I can set up that will do this automatically every time scrapy finds HTML? That way I don't have to go add this code to each parse() function and parse_item() function in my codebase.

Once I have that setup, is there a way I can check all previous URLs to tell scrapy to either pull from the live webpage or our S3 bucket?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to write your own [HTTPCACHE Storage](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#writing-your-own-storage-backend).

> ## Writing your own storage backend
>
> You can implement a cache storage backend by creating a Python class that defines the methods described below.
>
> ### `class scrapy.extensions.httpcache.CacheStorage`
>
> #### `open_spider(spider)`
>
> This method gets called after a spider has been opened for crawling. It handles the open_spider signal.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - spider (Spider object) – the spider which has been opened
>
> #### `close_spider(spider)`
>
> This method gets called after a spider has been closed. It handles the close_spider signal.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - spider (Spider object) – the spider which has been closed
>
> #### `retrieve_response(spider, request)`
>
> Return response if present in cache, or None otherwise.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - **spider** (Spider object) – the spider which generated the request
> - **request** (Request object) – the request to find cached reponse for
>
> #### `store_response(spider, request, response)`
>
> Store the given response in the cache.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - spider (Spider object) – the spider for which the response is intended
> - request (Request object) – the corresponding request the spider generated
> - response (Response object) – the response to store in the cache
>
> In order to use your storage backend, set:
>
> `HTTPCACHE_STORAGE` to the Python import path of your custom storage class.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `DownloaderMiddleware` in settings and write the code in `process_response` where you will get all the responses.